# Logging Into Website Using Python Requests With Sessions

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, csrf

I am looking into a website and am collecting the token for the cookie, but I am still not getting status as logged in.

Here is my code:

```
headers = {'Referer': 'https://www..com/accounts/login/'}

s = requests.Session()
# Get cookie
s.get('https://www..com/accounts/login/')
csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']

payload = {
    'id_username': 'my_username',
    'id_password': 'my_password',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
}

p = s.post('https://www..com/accounts/login/', data=payload, headers=headers)
print(p.text)
```

I do not see an obvious error when printing p.text, however, the printed HTML still shows 'Log In' rather than my username in its place which is what happens when I log in using a browser.

Can you see what I might be missing? My thought is that the csrf token was reset again after login, but how can I capture that when it is passed in the login call?

Thank you.

Comment: Add proper `headers` in your login request.

Comment: mks212 keep in mind, that no one would have been able to solve this one, with the edits you made. Knowing which sites source to read was crucial for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here to take the bounty :P

Your code is just fine. Even the referer-header is well formed.

But this is how your payload should look like:

```
payload = {
    'username': 'my_username',
    'password': 'my_password',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
}
```

You always go by the name of the field with these requests, not by the id.
I just logged in successfully.

Good luck with the project and remember to implement safeguards, when playing with anything but toy-money.

ps.: the only other missing payload would be "next" but is apparently not necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Aiyion.Prime. The bounty is all yours!